# Bmp Image Disappears after some time and on console scroll using gdi32

Tags: c++, console-application, gdi

I am trying to display a chessboard using gdi32 library, I am using this function for displaying bmp images. But the image disappears after sometimes. It also disappears when you try to scroll up/down the console. Then I have to recompile the program. Please help me here, how can this problem be solved.

```
void LoadBitmapAndDisplay( int xScreen, int yScreen, char* image )
{
        HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);


        HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(NULL,image, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE );

        HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hBmp);

        BITMAP bmp;
        GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
        BitBlt(hdc, xScreen, yScreen, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        DeleteObject(hBmp);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, displaying a image to a window is like drawing to a blackboard with a chalk. The blackboard is your screen and when things "move" around, they get actually redrawn. And whatever was there before, gets erased and lot to oblivion.

Your program received events from the OS. One of these events is `WM_PAINT` which is sent whenever your window needs to redraw its stuff, because it got uncovered or something swept over it, clobbering its contents.

Comment: I agree with you.I tried to call this function in an infinite loop, but still the image disappears and doesn't reappear again.

Comment: You should *not* call your function in an infinite loop. Put it in your WM_PAINT handler! (Which is used in, well, not an *infinite* loop, but as far as your process is concerned it is.) You may want to load the image earlier on.